# destroy the database- android life cycle

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-lifecycle

Hello I am trying to figure out a way to destroy my database every time the application starts either by returning from the background or reopen after it was closed. The issue is that when I am trying to run my application for the first time I get a null and my application crushes.

**My application:**
The user is prompt with a login screen and I create the db, move to another activity to perform a query. From this activity the user cannot go back to login, and will be only able to go to the phone home screen. When I will go to the home screen and re open the application I want to wipe out the db and start like it is my first time the user uses the application.
I know that this is not actually practical for an application, but this is just for learning.

I tried to do `db.close()` and `context.deleteDatabase(db.getPath());` in `onResume` and `onRestart`, but this always crushes my application. I also tried to check that 'db.getPath()!=null' , but this did not help either.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are aware that is not the most practical way to use databases I guess I won't bug you for that.

What you want to do is not to call the method to delete the database content during on Resume() or on Restart(), you actually want to call that via on Stop().

The method you want to use is

```
db.delete(String table, string whereClause, String [] whereArgs);
```

Passing the name of the table you want to delete, i.e "user_food_database", a whereclause which would be **null** in your case since you want to delete ALL rows, and null for whereArgs.

Here's the official doc:

"Convenience method for deleting rows in the database.

Parameters
table  the table to delete from 
whereClause  the optional WHERE clause to apply when deleting. Passing null will delete all rows.

Returns
the number of rows affected if a whereClause is passed in, 0 otherwise. To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" as the whereClause. "

You can also call:

```
deleteDatabase(File pathToDatabase)
```

in case you have more than one table in your database, but recreating the database itself everytime is expensive, and deleting only the content may result better.

Comment: for some reason drop table does not work in my case. I tried to put drop in my onCreate of my login but this did not work. as for onStop, should i put it in the login or in the other activity?

Comment: why would you call drop table? Call db.delete as I mentioned in the comment. And you can do that from any activity, as long as you have a reference to the database, remember, regardless of the activity you are on, it IS still the same database.

Comment: Can you also post some lines from the log when the app fails to do what you are asking it to do?

Comment: I deleted the update, because I found the reason for my error. I do have three follow up questions. 

a) why doing drop table does not do the trick?
b) what would be a better practice to empty a database, assuming I do have to start fresh in case of switching users (each user has its own db)
c)`deleteDatabase(File pathToDatabase)` , when doing this to delete all tables how do you get the actual file?

Comment: a) Drop Table is more for when you are updating the database version, it is recommended to use the pre-built methods such as deleteDatabase() or db.delete() for better control.

Comment: b) Why would you have a user login some many different times in your same app, assuming most of the times, only one user has the phone?

Comment: c) You do not get a "file", you only pass a path. like "/myapp/files/sometable.db"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you simply wipe the database, i.e., delete all data (or even drop the tables). This is not a direct answer to your question, but has the same effect.

Comment: that what I am trying to do , but I am not sure how to , because I am getting an null error

Comment: Try `db.delete(myTable, null, null)`. See also: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Answer (score 0):

Just drop all tables in the `open()` method of your `SQLiteDatabaseHelper` and recreate the tables by calling `onCreate(db)`. Works of course only when you are opening the db only once per app start.